# How can I make a dismissible alert in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I can display an alert, but I can't close it. But why?

the code:

```
showGeneralDialog(
        barrierColor: Colors.red,
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
        transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation animation,
            Animation secondaryAnimation) {
          if (shouldDismiss) {
            Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(true);
            });
          }
          return SomeWidget();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was in the

```
SomeWidget()
```

There is a children inside it, called `WillPopScope()` and this widget have a parameter: `onWillPop: () async => bool` this boolean was `false`, that's why I could not close...

Answer (score 1):

replace this

```dart
 Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(true);
```

by this

```dart
 Navigator.of(buildContext, rootNavigator: true).pop(true);
```

Comment: The buildContext's size is equivalent of my phone's size. Is this okay for alerts? I mean, technically I can't click outside of it.

Comment: make  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(true);
inside widget in pagebuilder